# Блокировка кнопок в c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

При запуске программы кнопка [старт] уже выделяется (скриншот ниже) и если я нажму пробел то кнопка активируется (идентично тому что если бы я нажал ЛКМ), но как сделать чтобы активация была тока через ЛКМ и кнопка не выделялась так.

[image: программа]

Comment: Ради всего святого, не ломайте стандартный UX! Пользователи испокон веков привыкли пользоваться Tab + Space. Оставьте им эту возможность.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы кнопка не получала фокус при нажатии кнопки Tab, установите у неё свойство `TabStop = false`.

Если дополнительно хочется, чтобы кнопка вообще не получала фокус при клике на ней мышкой, в обработчике события `Click` этой кнопки передавайте фокус на любой другой компонент, способный принимать фокус. Если таких компонентов на форме (кроме кнопок) нет, тады ой - это невозможно.

```
private void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // другой код

    someTextBox.Focus();
}
```

---

Мои действия, когда я встречаю приложения, ломающие привычный стандарт взаимодействия, принятый в данной ОС: uninstall. Dixi.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Comment: А как отключить пробел-то? например гляжу фильм, надо поставить паузу и если я нажму пробел то нужная форма закроется, что не желательно. хочу чтобы тока по ЛКМ типа закрывало, ну или enter (но лучше ЛКМ, или сразу ЛКМ или Enter две кнопки тока)

Comment: @user287413 - в моём ответе всё написано, как отключить.

Comment: Так это тока про фокус, а клик нет.

Comment: @user287413 - Если фокус не на кнопке, то нажатие на пробел не нажмёт на неё. Что тут непонятно???